# How to transfer system language settings to cobalt

Tags: cobalt

For example, our whole system set language to swe, then I want to let YouTube UI also show in Swedish.
But no find API to do so.

Answer (score 0):

To confirm that the system settings are appropriately getting propagated up to Cobalt, you can look in your implementation of /src/starboard/system.h::SbSystemGetLocaleId() to check that the value is expected is there.

Cobalt only queries the platform for its system language once upon startup, so to pick up the system language change, a full relaunch(non suspend-resume) of the app is required.